# Freemarker while loop to store numbers into variables

Tags: freemarker

I am trying to find out how I can take a piece of data (being delivered to me in a .txt file in a single column) which will contain a number, anywhere from 1-999999 and read each digit and store each one into a separate variable to use later. I am new to Freemarker so I haven't had much in the way of manuals or documentation to go on, and I am not even sure its a While loop I need to complete this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  I think you want to loop over an input file, which has a number on each line, and store the numbers you find in a variable.  Is that correct?  Pseudocode might help.

Comment: Sorry for my earlier comment, new at this. For greater context i am trying to take a value in a column, say "Miles Earned" which for myself would be 6756. I would like to read that number, and assign 6 into variable1, and 7 into variable2, 5 into variable3 and finally 6 into variable3.  From there.

Comment: Sorry, I realised I have explained this wrong.

Comment: Let me start from the beginning. I am doing an email, and the tool we are using to deploy these emails accepts Freemarker. The client wishes to take a number passed along in the data, and display it as fancy looking images.  I have these numbers, 0-9, created as images, called 0.jpg, 1.jpg.

If a collector in this dataset has a value of 6756,i need tio display 6.jpg, 7.jpg. 5.jpg and 6,jpg. Is there a way to echo these images out next to each other to create the final 6756 in the images.

Comment: Instead of adding comments, please update your question to improve it.

Comment: What have you tried and how did it fail? What part of the task is the problem? (Does having a `.txt` file have any relevance?)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to print the number with images as digits, then just add the number to the data-model (let's say with name `miles` and value 6756), and then for example define a FreeMacro macro:

```
<#macro numberAsImages n>
  <#local s = n?c>
  <#list 0 ..* s?length as i>
    <img href="cid:digit${s[i]}" alt="${s[i]}"><#t>
  </#list>
</#macro>
```

which later you can use as:

```
<@numberAsImages miles />
```

which will print this:

```
<img href="cid:digit6" alt="6"><img href="cid:digit7" alt="7"><img href="cid:digit5" alt="5"><img href="cid:digit6" alt="6">
```

Note that `?c` should only be used if `n` is not a string already, but a number (which is what it should be, i.e., generally, you should parse a number coming from a `.txt` before putting it into the data-model).

Comment: I am going to give this a try today, thank you so much in advance.  If i could be of further bother, as i am VERY new to Freemarker, could you explain what teh first 2 lines do?

<#macro numberAsImages n>
  <#local s = n?c>

Comment: There's a Manual, please try to find answers there first: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/index.html